# cast from char to long

Tags: c, typecast-operator

I am starting to learn the basics of buffer overflows. I came across a code where the function call which is supposed to happen once can be made to happen twice by modifying the flow that instead of pointing return address at the end of execution of the function, the code points to the beginning address of the function. Here's the code:

```
int main()

    {
      int i=0; char buf[44];
      for (i=0;i<=40;i+=4)
        *(long *) &buf[i] = 0x80484cb;
      puts(buf);
    }
```

What does `*(long *) &buf[i]` mean? I know its the very basics of C but need little help over here.

Comment: 'I am starting to learn the basics of buffer overflows' really?  Is 'don't let it happen in your code' not sufficient?

Comment: 3 completely different cases of undefined behavior in 3 lines. Impressive. Accessing an array out-of-bounds, violating strict aliasing and passing a non-string to `puts`. The code does nothing deterministic or meaningful, there is nothing to learn from it. At best, it will just crash. The person who wrote this code is nobody you should be learning from.

Answer (score 2):

The code is a mess and the behaviour *undefined* due to casting of unrelated types. (Although you can *always* cast to `char*`, the converse is not necessarily true since `buf[0]` might not be aligned correctly for a `long`.)

In short, each iteration of the loop is an attempt to *cast* a pointer to `char` to a pointer to `long`, *pretenting* that there is an `long` at that location to which `0x80484cb` can be assigned.

It is also assuming that `sizeof(long)` is 4 which is dubious to say the least.

The behaviour of `puts` will be *undefined* since `buf` doesn't necessarily point to the start of a `char` array that contains the null-terminator `\0`.

A far safer way would be to perform the pointer arithmetic directly on the `char` array, assigning portions of `0x80484cb` as you go.

Comment: Actually, you can always cast to **unsigned** char. There is no such guarantee for plain `char`, it just happens to work on most platforms. (6.2.6 Representation of types)